# ABCMeta object argument after ** must be a mapping, not GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

I've developed a Decision Tree with GridSearchCV. When I try to export the tree with export graphviz I get an error which I do not understand. I don't use an ABCMeta object at all.

```
from sklearn import tree

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', tfidf_vectorizer),  
    ('clf', DecisionTreeClassifier()),  
])
grid_dt = GridSearchCV(
    pipeline,  
    param_grid=params_dt,  # parameters to tune
    # refit=True,  n_jobs=-1,  
    scoring='accuracy', cv=10
)

dt_fit = grid_dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

with open('dtvis.dot', 'w') as file:
    tree.export_graphviz(dt_fit , out_file = "dtvis.dot", feature_names=terms, class_names=True)
file.close()

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['dot', '-Tpdf', 'dtvis.dot', '-o' 'dtvis.pdf'])
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../dt.py", line 241, in <module>
    dt_grid = DecisionTreeClassifier(**dt_fit)
TypeError: ABCMeta object argument after ** must be a mapping, not GridSearchCV
```

New Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../dt.py", line 245, in <module>
    export_graphviz(dt_fit, out_file = "dtvis.dot", feature_names=terms, class_names=True) 
  .../export.py", line 403, in export_graphviz
    recurse(decision_tree.tree_, 0, criterion=decision_tree.criterion)
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'tree_'
```

Could this be the culprit (tree.export_graphviz): tree.export_graphviz() vs. export_graphviz() ? When it worked the clf was tree.DecisionTreeClassifier and tree.export_graphviz. I tried with and without these prefixes in both lines without success.
Any suggestions or idea would be well appreciated!

Comment: Please show the complete traceback.

Comment: @BrenBarn ok, thanks !

Comment: You can see that that error occurs before you get to the graphviz part of your code, so graphviz has nothing to do with it.  What are you intending that code to do?  `dt_fit` is a fitted classifier object; how do you expect to create a new classifier from that?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the fitted classifier object using GridSearchCV to graphviz so that it outputs the tree. Previously when I just ran a simple classifier tree.DecisionTreeClassifier() without GridSearchCV I had no issues. I'll update the code I have now.

Comment: Your fitted classifier object is `dt_fit`.  Why are you trying to create *another* classifier object?

Comment: No real reason other than looking at someones code and trying that, as I was out of idea. Stupid I know.

Comment: In your updated example, you never do anything with the `pipeline` object, so I suspect this isn't your actual code.

Comment: @BrenBarn - I was editing the code before posting it, so there was mistake in the snippet. This is my code though I obviously didn't invent it but followed guidelines , tutorials etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing your graphviz call on `dt_fit.best_estimator_`:

```
tree.export_graphviz(dt_fit.best_estimator_ , out_file = "dtvis.dot", feature_names=terms, class_names=True)
```

`dt_fit` is a GridSearchCV object, which could be wrapping any kind of model, not just a tree, so it can't be plotted as a tree.  To plot it as a tree, you need to get the "real" underlying model that GridSearchCV found, which is what's given by `best_estimator_`.

Comment: thanks for this. I also had to add (best_estimator_.named_steps['clf']) for it to run. Without it I get an error: 'AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'tree_'